# Tableau - Multiple data into one graph, with double dimension on the x-axis

Tags: tableau-api

I'm very new to Tableau, and (maybe because of that) struggling with a graph setting. I need to plot a simple line graph showing the ratio between the number of users that returned after registered x days ago and the total number of users that registered x days ago (regardless on the fact that they returned or not). To do this, I have two tables: TableA having (simplifying) USER_ID and DATE_REGISTRATION, and TableB USER_ID and VISIT_DATE. Both table are joined by USER_ID.

I'm able, of course, to plot each individually (i.e. count distinct of USER_ID with DATE_REGISTRATION on the x axis to get the number of new users registered per day), but not able to combine them. I guess the problem is that I'm using either DATE_REGISTRATION or VISIT_DATE on the x-axis, but in this case I can get one or the other info, but not the two combined.

Ultimately, I would like to be able to have, for each date, both the number of users visiting and the number of user who registered.
Thanks a lot in advance.
Raffaele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, problem is your database is not ready to generate those analysis. Your table is user_id oriented, meaning you can do lots of analysis centered on the user_id. To do date oriented you need a table like:

```
Date         User_id    Type of event
01/01/2014   1234       Registration
02/01/2014   1234       Visit
```

Then you can drag Date and Type of event to Columns, and COUNTD(User_id) to rows, to get a bar chart that will show, for each day, how many people registered that day and how many people visited that same day.

Additionally, you can still join this table with the one you have, to have the registration date for each user_id. That way you can, for instance, calculate how many days have passed since registration.